# How to design a GUI using GLCD?

Tags: lcd, glcd

I have a small project that I'm working on. It has a NOKIA 5110 LCD.
I want to make a nice GUI to view measurements, and also control the hardware.
I've designed tow screen layouts which you can see in the images below
[image]

[image]

the thing is if I complete the code the way I did it(the code is at the end), it will be big.
And I don't think this is the optimal way to make a multiple screen layouts.
It would be great if any one could help or give me a head tips.

This is the code for "ok" button:

```
if(bit_is_clear(PINC, 5))
    {
        UART_Send_String("OK\n");
        switch(screenIndex)
        {
        case HOME_LAYOUT:
            switch(cursor_index)
            {
            case 5:
                lcdSetupLayout();
                cursor_index = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        case LCD_SETUP_LAYOUT:
            switch(cursor_index)
            {
            case 0:
                PCD8544_send_command(video_inverse);
                break;
            case 1:
                PCD8544_send_command(display_norm);
                break;
            case 3:
                cursor_index = 0;
                homeLayout();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        _delay_ms(300);
    }
```

And this is the code for "up" button ("down" button has a similar thing)

```
if(bit_is_clear(PINC, 6))
    {
        UART_Send_String("UP\n");
        if(cursor_index > 0)
        {
            set_x_y(0,cursor_index);
            PCD8544_send_char(' ');
            set_x_y(0,--cursor_index);
            PCD8544_send_char('>');
        }
        else
        {
            set_x_y(0,cursor_index);
            PCD8544_send_char(' ');
            cursor_index = 5;
            set_x_y(0,cursor_index);
            PCD8544_send_char('>');
        }
        _delay_ms(300);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. So what's your point? That you have a lot of coding to do for a GUI? You bet you do. You may have hundreds of sub-routines by the time you are done.

Comment: so this is normal, i thought there is a smarter way to do it. any way thanks Sparky256

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain level of complexity where hand coding the menus becomes very cumbersome. Part of the issue is that you are coding the menu handling again and again.

What can be done is to separate the menu from the menu code. You can use a const struct array to define the menu, and use function pointers to get custom strings, etc. It can get pretty complex quickly, but definitely is worth it for menu trees in the 100's of options. Making menu changes becomes trivial.

Ideas from code:

1. Use strings to define menu levels, like "1.2.3" would be parsed to show under "1.2"
2. Use strings to define menu actions
3. Use enums to define menu item type
4. Use function pointers to retrieve custom options.
5. Use function pointer arrays to build the active displayed menu.
6. Menu structure is stored in a const struct array.
7. Menu layout points can be stored as a string like "X10Y20" or as an array.

Answer (score 0):

reduce your "UP" button code like this

look for other similar areas

think clearly about what the code does at every point in the program listing

note: your indentation is slightly inconsistent

```
if(bit_is_clear(PINC, 6))
{
    UART_Send_String("UP\n");

    set_x_y(0,cursor_index);        // roll these two lines into a function if they repeat a lot 
    PCD8544_send_char(' ');

    if(cursor_index = 0)  cursor_index = 6; 

    set_x_y(0,--cursor_index);      // decrements cursor_index before calling set_x_y()
    PCD8544_send_char('>');

    _delay_ms(300);
}
```